# Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: range out of order in character class at offset 54

Tags: php, preg-match

Any idea how to fix this error? The coding is as per below.

```
if ( preg_match( "#^" . $r['match'] . "$#is", $matches[2] ) )
```

i also get the same error on another different line of my code. The coding is as per below.

```
if ( preg_match( "#^" . $r['match'] . "$#is", $url ) )
```

Comment: What is `$r['match']`?  We can't help unless we know what the actual regex you're trying to use is.

Comment: can you produce a dump of $matches[2], $url and $r['match']? Maybe it could help

Comment: There's probably an unescaped hyphen in $r['match'].

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that $r[match] contains characters that aren't defined in the charset used by php. Php isn't using Unicode a lot, so e.g. if it were set to plain ASCII, it would complain about any umlaut in a string.